# REST Web service android client

Tags: android, wcf

I was create a WCF Web Service and I want to consume it in a android client 
I have a problem and I can't find it .
If I put a other link like this link : http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt my client works.

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                                   UriTemplate = "GetData.txt")]
        string GetData();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                                  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                                  UriTemplate = "GetDataUsingDataContract/")]
        List GetDataUsingDataContract();

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Web Config code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="tbl">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"  behaviorConfiguration="tbl">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:52570/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

android code

```html
package com.example.algorismi.myapplication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public final String feelURL = "http://10.0.2.2:52570/Service1.svc/GetData.txt";
   // public final String feelURL = "http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt"; // Lien fonctionne

    String responseString;
    TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyAsyncTask mytask = new MyAsyncTask();
        mytask.execute("Sending parameter","Second param");
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        public StringBuffer buffer;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String myFirstParam = params[0];
           // StringBuffer buffer;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            HttpURLConnection client = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(feelURL);
                client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                client.connect();
                Log.i("Connexion", "Connexion est etablie avec succée");

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                Log.i("Connexion", buffer.toString());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(client != null)
                client.disconnect();
                try {
                    if(reader != null)
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i("Algorismi", "Terminée");
            return myFirstParam;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
            txt.setText(buffer.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the programming question ? What can't you find ?

Comment: Here is my code of my service web and android client

Comment: Make sure your port(10.0.2.2:`52570`) is not blocked by Firewall. Try telnet on this port from another machine if it shows error then you need to write an Inbound rule for firewall. Simply you can test it by turning off the firewall on hosting machine if that works add an Inbound rule to the windows firewall for your port.